# Magento 2 giving error no category save. Error is - No such entity with id = xx

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2 We are getting error on category save. Error is - No such entity with id = xx please any one can help to resolve the same ?

Thank you.

[click to see screen shot for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXSpd.png)

Answer (score 4):

It happened to me also, in version 2.2.0.

In my case the problem was the `url_rewrite` table.
Check the "metadata" column of the `url_rewrite` table for non-existent categories and delete those rows.

The problem are the `url_rewrite` rows of products belonging to that category.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your site is in `Developer Mode`, you can change it to `Production Mode` and clear/flush cache and then switch back to `Developer Mode`.

I had this issue in the front end, as i recently moved the datatbase from one server to another. I have managed to solve by this way.

Answer (score 0):

Please make indexing and recheck. If you are using any third party extension then this issue also occur. If you have deleted any category from any store then this may also happen. Please check all things hope your issue will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin Marketing -> URL Rewrite
And search in the target path with specific id category or product where you have an issue.
Then delete the entry where entity with `id = xx`.
Go back your category or product page and try to save again.